# Issue with Git blob API: 502 Server Error

Tags: python-3.x, github, aws-lambda, github-api, server-error

I am reading a tree from a repository using [Git tree API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/trees#get-a-tree) and creating all the blobs in another repository using [Git blob API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/blobs#create-a-blob). But I am receiving 502 server error. This behaviour is intermittent. And, the probability of this failure on AWS Lambda is quite high than in local.

The problem looks like from the GiHub side. Please help with this.

Please find the script below. [Here](https://github.com/raj-gondalia-ik/git-api) is the repository from which I am reading the tree.

```
import json
import requests
import time

BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/repos/raj-gondalia-ik/git-api/git"


def call_github_api(method, url, params={}, data={}):
    data = json.dumps(data)
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
        "Authorization": "token <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>",
    }
    response = requests.request(
        method,
        url,
        headers=headers,
        params=params,
        data=data,
    )
    response_dict = response.json()
    response_str = json.dumps(response_dict, indent=4)
    if not (200 <= response.status_code < 300):
        error_message = (
            f"GitHub API returned non 2xx HTTP status code."
            f"\n"
            f"\nmethod = {method}"
            f"\nurl = {url}"
            f"\nparams = {params}"
            f"\ndata = {data}"
            f"\n"
            f"\nresponse.status_code = {response.status_code}"
            f"\nresponse_str = {response_str}"
            f"\n"
        )
        print(f"call_github_api failure: error_message = {error_message}")
        raise Exception("API failure")
    return response_dict


def get_blob_content(blob_sha):
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/blobs/{blob_sha}"
    response_dict = call_github_api("get", url)
    return {"content": response_dict["content"], "encoding": response_dict["encoding"]}


def create_a_blob(content, encoding):
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/blobs"
    data = {"content": content, "encoding": encoding}
    call_github_api("post", url, data=data)


def copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo(from_repo_blob):
    print(f"copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {from_repo_blob}")
    from_blob_content = get_blob_content(from_repo_blob["sha"])
    print(f'Length of {from_repo_blob["path"]} is {len(from_blob_content["content"])}')
    print(f"Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {from_repo_blob}")
    create_a_blob(
        from_blob_content["content"],
        from_blob_content["encoding"],
    )
    print(f"Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {from_repo_blob}")


def copy_blobs(from_repo_blobs):
    start = time.time()
    for from_repo_blob in from_repo_blobs:
        copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo(from_repo_blob)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"copy_blobs took {end - start}s to execute")


def get_tree_from_tree_sha(tree_sha):
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/trees/{tree_sha}"
    response_dict = call_github_api("get", url, {"recursive": True})
    tree = []
    for item in response_dict["tree"]:
        if item["type"] == "blob":
            tree.append({"sha": item["sha"], "path": item["path"]})
    return tree


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from_repo_blobs = get_tree_from_tree_sha("85b396da024386d8acaefc5ab91c173c5cd6eb86")
    copy_blobs(from_repo_blobs)
```

Below is one of the failure output result.

```
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'e3566aa5f6e5317dd87465ea518c0cd5fbbd94f0', 'path': '.DS_Store'}
Length of .DS_Store is 8337
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'e3566aa5f6e5317dd87465ea518c0cd5fbbd94f0', 'path': '.DS_Store'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'e3566aa5f6e5317dd87465ea518c0cd5fbbd94f0', 'path': '.DS_Store'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'd721f2054f92845980a001a0d1881ed755a09ffc', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/.DS_Store'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/.DS_Store is 8337
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'd721f2054f92845980a001a0d1881ed755a09ffc', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/.DS_Store'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'd721f2054f92845980a001a0d1881ed755a09ffc', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/.DS_Store'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': '547e82bddd2646478b3298f0e9c76c5f9fbea18a', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/README.md'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/README.md is 1042
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '547e82bddd2646478b3298f0e9c76c5f9fbea18a', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/README.md'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '547e82bddd2646478b3298f0e9c76c5f9fbea18a', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/README.md'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'a9c725598eb71a4e7d5f10ad9cd0fbcc4c0ab154', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/VERSION'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/VERSION is 139
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'a9c725598eb71a4e7d5f10ad9cd0fbcc4c0ab154', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/VERSION'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'a9c725598eb71a4e7d5f10ad9cd0fbcc4c0ab154', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/VERSION'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'e3e4253938fbcca0a9b8cfee11e6cb6eb54f37bd', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/common'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/common is 8394
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'e3e4253938fbcca0a9b8cfee11e6cb6eb54f37bd', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/common'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'e3e4253938fbcca0a9b8cfee11e6cb6eb54f37bd', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/common'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': '0ffaed18652c256321c7f274337228dbbc00e526', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/common.bat'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/common.bat is 4035
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '0ffaed18652c256321c7f274337228dbbc00e526', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/common.bat'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '0ffaed18652c256321c7f274337228dbbc00e526', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/common.bat'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'b81376d1738ab56ca8e0b734cb06f856f05467e1', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scala'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/scala is 1281
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'b81376d1738ab56ca8e0b734cb06f856f05467e1', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scala'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'b81376d1738ab56ca8e0b734cb06f856f05467e1', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scala'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'edf7bfc5a1c2c2692389b3ef24a2ea61171e0fe9', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scala.bat'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/scala.bat is 5019
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'edf7bfc5a1c2c2692389b3ef24a2ea61171e0fe9', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scala.bat'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'edf7bfc5a1c2c2692389b3ef24a2ea61171e0fe9', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scala.bat'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': '6ebf0fe70ea83762ef3655f742d4c2c7f021d2c8', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac is 3567
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '6ebf0fe70ea83762ef3655f742d4c2c7f021d2c8', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '6ebf0fe70ea83762ef3655f742d4c2c7f021d2c8', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'bf34f9275aabab3fccbdc9daf75195499d03dd67', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac.bat'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac.bat is 6865
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'bf34f9275aabab3fccbdc9daf75195499d03dd67', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac.bat'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'bf34f9275aabab3fccbdc9daf75195499d03dd67', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scalac.bat'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'f09bf27812c069675c1132c509690747b0f5535f', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc is 5901
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'f09bf27812c069675c1132c509690747b0f5535f', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'f09bf27812c069675c1132c509690747b0f5535f', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'c7eb4cb6d47246a3802c2e2e91e025fda78ba7e4', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc.bat'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc.bat is 6239
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'c7eb4cb6d47246a3802c2e2e91e025fda78ba7e4', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc.bat'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'c7eb4cb6d47246a3802c2e2e91e025fda78ba7e4', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/bin/scaladoc.bat'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': '28d599564be03af09aa7a70dac340cc6ca0bf2f2', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-asm-9.1.0-scala-1.jar'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-asm-9.1.0-scala-1.jar is 423121
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '28d599564be03af09aa7a70dac340cc6ca0bf2f2', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-asm-9.1.0-scala-1.jar'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '28d599564be03af09aa7a70dac340cc6ca0bf2f2', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-asm-9.1.0-scala-1.jar'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': '16695c89fbf7b4a4fae2e369ab04bbd9d223308e', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-library-2.13.6.jar'}
Length of scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-library-2.13.6.jar is 8073334
Going to create a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '16695c89fbf7b4a4fae2e369ab04bbd9d223308e', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-library-2.13.6.jar'}
Created a blob for from_repo_blob = {'sha': '16695c89fbf7b4a4fae2e369ab04bbd9d223308e', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/lib/scala-library-2.13.6.jar'}
copy_a_blob_from_from_repo_to_to_repo: from_repo_blob = {'sha': 'f6cd5216a41f2d1c1f10d56aae2409ebab5af259', 'path': 'scala-3.1.0/lib/scala3-compiler_3-3.1.0.jar'}
call_github_api failure: error_message = GitHub API returned non 2xx HTTP status code.

method = get
url = https://api.github.com/repos/raj-gondalia-ik/git-api/git/blobs/f6cd5216a41f2d1c1f10d56aae2409ebab5af259
params = {}
data = {}

response.status_code = 502
response_str = {
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```